# Setting values in pandas Series is slow, why?

Tags: python, pandas

#### Question

Does anyone know why setting an item directly on a pandas series is so incredibly slow? Am I doing something wrong, or is it just the way it is?

I ran a couple of tests to see what the fastest method is to set a value on a pandas Series object. Here are the results, ordered from fast to slow:

#### initialize array, set using integer index, create series

```
%%timeit
a = np.empty(1000, dtype='float')
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = 1.0
s = pd.Series(data=a)
```

1000 loops, best of 3: 630 µs per loop

#### create empty list, add item using append, create series

```
%%timeit
l = []
for i in range(1000):
    l.append(1.0)
s = pd.Series(data=l)
```

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.05 ms per loop

#### initialize array, create series, set using set_value

```
%%timeit
a = np.empty(1000, dtype='float')
s = pd.Series(data=a)
for i in range(len(a)):
    s.set_value(i, 1.0)
```

100 loops, best of 3: 18.5 ms per loop

#### initialize array, create series, set using integer index

```
%%timeit
a = np.empty(1000, dtype='float')
s = pd.Series(data=a)
for i in range(len(a)):
    s[i] = 1.0
```

10 loops, best of 3: 30.2 ms per loop

#### intialize array, create series, set using iat

```
%%timeit
a = np.empty(1000, dtype='float')
s = pd.Series(data=a)
for i in range(len(a)):
    s.iat[i] = 1.0
```

10 loops, best of 3: 36.2 ms per loop

#### initialize array, create series, set using iloc

```
%%timeit
a = np.empty(1000, dtype='float')
s = pd.Series(data=a)
for i in range(len(a)):
    s.iloc[i] = 1.0
```

1 loops, best of 3: 280 ms per loop

Comment: Your timings are also timing the creation of the Series.  Try creating the Series beforehand and timing only the set operation.

Comment: Try `s.iat[i] = 1.0` the indexing methods here perform some checks I believe: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#fast-scalar-value-getting-and-setting I get 159ms for `iloc` versus 23.3ms for `iat` version

Comment: @BrenBarn: I tried timing only the creation of the array and the series, but that takes only 172 microseconds

Comment: @EdChum: edited my answer to include setting with s.iat[i]. It performs slightly worse than s[i]...

Comment: Yes I observe the same thing, not sure why as such but it's significantly faster than `iloc`

Comment: There really should be a faster way you'd think. I mean: a series has a numpy array underneath right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#fast-scalar-value-getting-and-setting)

> Since indexing with [] must handle a lot of cases (single-label
>   access, slicing, boolean indexing, etc.), it has a bit of overhead in
>   order to figure out what you’re asking for.

So I get the following which should be comparable:

```
In [13]:

%%timeit
a = np.empty(1000,dtype='float')
s = pd.Series(data=a)
for i in range(len(a)):
    s.iat[i] = 1.0
10 loops, best of 3: 23.3 ms per loop
In [14]:

%%timeit
a = np.empty(1000,dtype='float')
s = pd.Series(data=a)
for i in range(len(a)):
    s.iloc[i] = 1.0
10 loops, best of 3: 159 ms per loop
```

for the other tests:

```
In [15]:

%%timeit
l = []
for i in range(1000):
    l.append(1.0)
s = pd.Series(data=l)
1000 loops, best of 3: 525 µs per loop
In [16]:

%%timeit
a = np.empty(1000,dtype='float')
s = pd.Series(data=a)
for i in range(len(a)):
    s.set_value(i,1.0)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.1 ms per loop
In [17]:

%%timeit
a = np.empty(1000,dtype='float')
s = pd.Series(data=a)
for i in range(len(a)):
    s[i] = 1.0
100 loops, best of 3: 17.5 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to get past the indexing overhead when setting values on a series object directly:

```
a = np.empty(1000,dtype='float')
s = pd.Series(data=a)
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = 1.0
```

When initializing the Series from a numpy array, the data is not copied. If a reference is kept to the original array, you can just set values on that!

Answer (score 1):

I think these methods are even faster for initializing a series to a constant value:

**Base Line**

```
%%timeit
a = np.empty(1000, dtype='float')
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = 1.0
s = pd.Series(data=a)

10000 loops, best of 3: 121 µs per loop
```

**Alternatives**

```
%%timeit
s = pd.Series(np.empty(1000, dtype='float')) * 1.

10000 loops, best of 3: 99.5 µs per loop

%%timeit
constant = 5.
s = pd.Series(np.ones(1000)) * constant

10000 loops, best of 3: 85.3 µs per loop
```

Comment: You are right of course. In my question I simplified the case where you calculate a different value every time to using just one constant value (to lazy to call a random generator). In fact, in my particular case, they aren't even ```float```'s but ```object```'s